# insert row into a matlab table at given idx

Tags: matlab

I would like to insert a row into a matlab table, but am having trouble finding an elegant way of doing this

A brief search of the documentation + google + a shout around the room did not return anything relevant (e.g see http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-and-delete-table-rows.html

For now I just re-create the table by vertcating before and after:

```
insert_idx = find(something in T)
T = vertcat(T(1:(insert_idx-1),:),...
                Tnew,...
                T(insert_idx:end,:));
```

is this the right way to insert row(s) into a matlab table and doesn't that seem a little inefficient?

Comment: you should use [row_idx,col_idx] = find(...). Do you know anything about the matrix? like how many rows have to be inserted. If not, I think your way is suitable.

Comment: I need to insert 1 row, and I know roughly that the matrix has 2000 rows except that it is not a matrix it is a table.